# How to fix You have requested a non-existent service 'database.replica_kill_switch'

Tags: drupal-8

I was trying to export a drupal site to local, and while doing "drush cr" iam receiving the following error 'You have requested a non-existent service "database.replica_kill_switch"', How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I found this error in an installation previous to 8.7.x, while updating to 8.8.x. this "database.replica_kill_switch" doesn't exist before 8.7.x. Maybe you have some module only compatible with 8.7.x and greater.

I solved my error, not sure if it applies to your case, with the following commands:

```sh
composer update
drush updatedb
# ignore if drush cr fails
drush cr
# make sure your composer.json requires twig/twig:^1.38.2
vi composer.json
composer update twig/twig
composer require drupal/core:8.7 --update-with-dependencies
drush updatedb
drush cr
```

Comment: yes you are correct, i had some modules which required drupal version 8.8 but i had only .6, thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice, @SathishSundar. I'm glad to be helpful. If my commands did help you, please mark my answer as solution. Thanks!